# Getting TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype when trying to use idxmax()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When using the `idxmax()` function in Pandas, I keep receiving this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/College/year-4/fyp-credit-card-fraud/code/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    best_c_param = classify.print_kfold_scores(X_training_undersampled, y_training_undersampled)
  File "/Users/username/College/year-4/fyp-credit-card-fraud/code/Classification.py", line 39, in print_kfold_scores
    best_c_param = results.loc[results['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1369, in idxmax
    i = nanops.nanargmax(_values_from_object(self), skipna=skipna)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 74, in _f
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name=f.__name__.replace('nan', '')))
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

The Pandas version I am using is `0.22.0`

main.py

```
import ExploratoryDataAnalysis as eda
import Preprocessing as processor
import Classification as classify
import pandas as pd


data_path = '/Users/username/college/year-4/fyp-credit-card-fraud/data/'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(data_path + 'creditcard.csv')
    # eda.init(df)
    # eda.check_null_values()
    # eda.view_data()
    # eda.check_target_classes()
    df = processor.noramlize(df)

    X_training, X_testing, y_training, y_testing, X_training_undersampled, X_testing_undersampled, \
    y_training_undersampled, y_testing_undersampled = processor.resample(df)

    best_c_param = classify.print_kfold_scores(X_training_undersampled, y_training_undersampled)
```

Classification.py

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, precision_recall_curve, auc, \
    roc_auc_score, roc_curve, recall_score, classification_report
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def print_kfold_scores(X_training, y_training):
    print('\nKFold\n')

    fold = KFold(len(y_training), 5, shuffle=False)

    c_param_range = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]

    results = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(c_param_range), 2), columns=['C_parameter', 'Mean recall score'])
    results['C_parameter'] = c_param_range

    j = 0
    for c_param in c_param_range:
        print('-------------------------------------------')
        print('C parameter: ', c_param)
        print('\n-------------------------------------------')

        recall_accs = []
        for iteration, indices in enumerate(fold, start=1):
            lr = LogisticRegression(C=c_param, penalty='l1')
            lr.fit(X_training.iloc[indices[0], :], y_training.iloc[indices[0], :].values.ravel())

            y_prediction_undersampled = lr.predict(X_training.iloc[indices[1], :].values)
            recall_acc = recall_score(y_training.iloc[indices[1], :].values, y_prediction_undersampled)
            recall_accs.append(recall_acc)
            print('Iteration ', iteration, ': recall score = ', recall_acc)

        results.ix[j, 'Mean recall score'] = np.mean(recall_accs)
        j += 1
        print('\nMean recall score ', np.mean(recall_accs))
        print('\n')

    best_c_param = results.loc[results['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter'] # Error occurs on this line

    print('*****************************************************************')
    print('Best model to choose from cross validation is with C parameter = ', best_c_param)
    print('*****************************************************************')

    return best_c_param
```

The line that is causing the problem is this

`best_c_param = results.loc[results['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter']`

The output of the program is below

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/username/College/year-4/fyp-credit-card-fraud/code/main.py
/Users/username/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:41: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Dataset Ratios

Percentage of genuine transactions:  0.5
Percentage of fraudulent transactions 0.5
Total number of transactions in resampled data:  984


Whole Dataset Split

Number of transactions in training dataset:  199364
Number of transactions in testing dataset:  85443
Total number of transactions in dataset:  284807


Undersampled Dataset Split

Number of transactions in training dataset 688
Number of transactions in testing dataset:  296
Total number of transactions in dataset:  984

KFold

-------------------------------------------
C parameter:  0.01

-------------------------------------------
Iteration  1 : recall score =  0.931506849315
Iteration  2 : recall score =  0.917808219178
Iteration  3 : recall score =  1.0
Iteration  4 : recall score =  0.959459459459
Iteration  5 : recall score =  0.954545454545

Mean recall score  0.9526639965


-------------------------------------------
C parameter:  0.1

-------------------------------------------
Iteration  1 : recall score =  0.849315068493
Iteration  2 : recall score =  0.86301369863
Iteration  3 : recall score =  0.915254237288
Iteration  4 : recall score =  0.945945945946
Iteration  5 : recall score =  0.909090909091

Mean recall score  0.89652397189


-------------------------------------------
C parameter:  1

-------------------------------------------
Iteration  1 : recall score =  0.86301369863
Iteration  2 : recall score =  0.86301369863
Iteration  3 : recall score =  0.983050847458
Iteration  4 : recall score =  0.945945945946
Iteration  5 : recall score =  0.924242424242

Mean recall score  0.915853322981


-------------------------------------------
C parameter:  10

-------------------------------------------
Iteration  1 : recall score =  0.849315068493
Iteration  2 : recall score =  0.876712328767
Iteration  3 : recall score =  0.983050847458
Iteration  4 : recall score =  0.945945945946
Iteration  5 : recall score =  0.939393939394

Mean recall score  0.918883626012


-------------------------------------------
C parameter:  100

-------------------------------------------
Iteration  1 : recall score =  0.86301369863
Iteration  2 : recall score =  0.876712328767
Iteration  3 : recall score =  0.983050847458
Iteration  4 : recall score =  0.945945945946
Iteration  5 : recall score =  0.924242424242

Mean recall score  0.918593049009


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/College/year-4/fyp-credit-card-fraud/code/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    best_c_param = classify.print_kfold_scores(X_training_undersampled, y_training_undersampled)
  File "/Users/username/College/year-4/fyp-credit-card-fraud/code/Classification.py", line 39, in print_kfold_scores
    best_c_param = results.loc[results['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1369, in idxmax
    i = nanops.nanargmax(_values_from_object(self), skipna=skipna)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 74, in _f
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name=f.__name__.replace('nan', '')))
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Two comments for those who end up here: 1. `argmax` method has been deprecated, use `idxmax` instead. 2. before doing anything check your type with `print(df['columnName'].dtype)` and make sure it is numeric (i.e. integer, float ...). if it returns just `object` then use `df['columnName'].astype(float)` instead.

Answer (score 31):

The type of the cell values are, by default, non-numeric. `argmin()`, `idxmin()`, `argmax()` and other similar functions need the dtypes to be numeric.

The easiest solution is to use `pd.to_numeric()` in order to convert your series (or columns) to numeric types. An example with a data frame `df` with a column `'a'` would be:

```
df['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'])
```

A more complete answer on type casting on pandas can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas/16134561).

Answer (score 9):

```
#best_c = results_table.loc[results_table['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter']
```

## We should replace this line of code

## The main problem:

1) the type of "mean recall score" is object, you can't use "idxmax()" to calculate the value 
2) you should change "mean recall score" from "object " to "float" 
3) you can use apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce', axis = 0) to do such things.

```
best_c = results_table
best_c.dtypes.eq(object) # you can see the type of best_c
new = best_c.columns[best_c.dtypes.eq(object)] #get the object column of the best_c
best_c[new] = best_c[new].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce', axis=0) # change the type of object
best_c
best_c = results_table.loc[results_table['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter'] #calculate the mean values
```

Comment: Welcome to SO !can you please elaborate a bit ? code-only answers might be considered as low quality and hence removed.

Comment: TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

The problem: 
1) the type of "mean recall score" is object, you can't use "idxmax()" to calculate the value
2) you should change "mean recall score" from "object " to "float"
3) you can use apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce', axis = 0) to do such things.

Comment: Please edit the question with all relevant information, thanks !

Answer (score 5):

In short, try this

```
best_c = results_table.loc[results_table['Mean recall score'].astype(float).idxmax()]['C_parameter']
```

instead of

```
best_c = results_table.loc[results_table['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter']
```

Answer (score 0):

If NaN are present (and we can sort of see this by the stack trace) then when you think you are working with a data frame of numerics, you could well have mixed types, and in particular, a string among numerics.  Let me give you 3 code examples, the first 2 work, the last doesn't and is likely your case.

This represents all numeric data, it will work with idxmax

```
the_dict = {}
the_dict['a'] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5]
the_dict['b'] = [0.3, 0.4, 0.6]
the_dict['c'] = [0.25, 0.3, 0.9]
the_dict['d'] = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
the_df = pd.DataFrame(the_dict)
```

This represents a numeric nan, it will work idxmax

```
the_dict = {}
the_dict['a'] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5]
the_dict['b'] = [0.3, 0.4, 0.6]
the_dict['c'] = [0.25, 0.3, 0.9]
the_dict['d'] = [0.2, 0.1, np.NaN]
the_df = pd.DataFrame(the_dict)
```

This could be the exact problem reported by the OP, but if it turns out we have mixed types in any fashion, we will get the error the OP reported.

```
the_dict = {}
the_dict['a'] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5]
the_dict['b'] = [0.3, 0.4, 0.6]
the_dict['c'] = [0.25, 0.3, 0.9]
the_dict['d'] = [0.2, 0.1, 'NaN']
the_df = pd.DataFrame(the_dict)
```