# Find and return max value for a column and the row of the max value as an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am working with a panda dataframe to try to find maximum values. I need to return the max value for a column as well as the row that max value was found in. For example, my dataframe looks like this:

```
       0    1    2
0     43   36   33
1     43   36   33
2     43   36   33
3     43   36   33
4     43   36   33
5     43   36   33
6    174  168  165
7    161  153  140
8    141  132  129
9    124  107  111
10   130  106  109
11   120   98  101
```

I want to return the maximum value for each column and the row that the max value was found in like the following as an array:

```
0   174   6
1   168   6
2   165   6
```

I've used:

```py
for column in df:
##    finds the max in each column
    df_max=np.amax(df,axis=0)
```

to get:

```
0   174
1   168
2   165
```

However, I haven't found a way to get the row value.

I've used:

```py
for column in df:
    row_df-df[df==np.amax(df,0)]

row_df=row_df.dropna(0,how='all')
print("row_df:")
print(row_df)

row_df_index=row_df.index.values
print("row_df_index")
print(row_df_index)
```

to get:

```
row_df:
       0    1    2
6     174   168   165

row_df_index:
[6]
```

But these won't help me if I have max values in other rows since I need to be able to match them up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) is the method which returns the index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.

So you could use [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to aggregate results:

```
df.agg(['max', 'idxmax'])
```

which returns:

```
          0    1    2
max     174  168  165
idxmax    6    6    6
```

If you need to have `max` and `idxmax` as columns, use [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
df.agg(['max', 'idxmax']).transpose()
```

which gives:

```
   max  idxmax
0  174       6
1  168       6
2  165       6
```

Comment: I'm having problems making this work.
```
row_df=df.idxmax(0)
```
yields "TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype".

Comment: @blurcifer not sure why you want to extract the column that way, but if `df` is your original dataframe `row_df=df.idxmax(0)` does not raise any error. So what is `df`?

Comment: @Valentino the dataframe is a csv file that has been transposed then sliced to produce dataframe df. It's 301 rows by 13290 columns with  type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>.

Its first few rows look like this when I print:
```
Timestamp 2018-10-21 16:14:23  ... 2018-10-21 23:58:58
0                          43  ...                  38
1                          43  ...                  38
2                          43  ...                  38
```

Comment: You have mixed types (integer and tmestamps), your real dataframe is different from the one you posted. Try reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719937/getting-typeerror-reduction-operation-argmax-not-allowed-for-this-dtype-when If is not helpful, you should maybe open another question.

Comment: After playing around with my data (slicing my initial dataframe differently and converting to floats), I got this to work. What I wrote isn't beautiful, but it works well enough. Thanks!